# convert curl post request to a fiddler/postman request

Tags: curl, request, postman, trace, fiddler

I am not familar with curl command much, I read about it commands and still have questions. How can I convert this curl command to generate post request in Fiddler or Postman so I can look at the trace of the calls? Tried the -- trace option for the curl command but reading the trace is not as easy as in other tools.
If I want to create a post request in fiddler with files and configs in this command, how can I do that? where in header or body I should put these values from curl?

```
cat file.msg | protoc --encode=GetNumbers proto.proto |  curl -k -sS -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-protobuf" --data-binary @-  https://localhost.com:8080/num/status/Type | protoc --decode=response proto.proto
```

Thank you very much for your help. Specifically I am looking for tracing a performance issue and to know which internal service is taking more time to respond. Would appreciate any word of wisdom

Comment: What you have posted is not a pure curl command, instead it generates the request and parses the response using a protobuf tool. Fiddler has not support for protobuf structures (creating and parsing). Not sure about Postman.

Answer (score 0):

The following command is a 3-step process that you have chained using the pipe operator ("|")

1. Load data from `file.msg` and encode/serialize it using the `GetNumbers.proto` schema
2. Make the cURL request with the output of Step1
3. De-serialize the response of the cURL request using the `response.proto` schema

   cat file.msg | protoc --encode=GetNumbers proto.proto |  curl -k -sS -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-protobuf" --data-binary @-  https://localhost.com:8080/num/status/Type | protoc --decode=response proto.proto

You can try using [Postman gRPC support](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/grpc/using-service-definition) but it might be an overkill. You'd be better off breaking down your steps manually and using any browser-based API Client like [Requestly API Client](https://app.requestly.io/api-client) or even Postman to debug your request then.

1. Execute `cat file.msg | protoc --encode=GetNumbers proto.proto` and copy the response in a text file or clipboard
2. Open the API Client and Import your cURL request, add the body
3. Save the response in a text file & Decode the response using `protoc --decode=response proto.proto`

If you only have to do it once, it can work but if you have to do it multiple times with different data/messages, then it'd be worth investing in Postman gRPC support.